# java,apache poi, как в excel таблице скрыть колонки

Tags: java, apache, excel, poi

нелегкая заставила меня связаться с excel таблицами. собсно вопрос. есть у меня таблица (50 столбцов), из нее нужно как нибудь достать 1 столбец с определенными данными и отправить на почту определенному юзеру, потом извлечь другой столбец и отправить следующему и тд. обычного копирования я как такового не нашел (хотя честно искал). был ли у кого опыт? нужен не готовый код, а хотя бы намек как это можно сделать.
thanks!

Comment: в каком виде отправить на почту?

Comment: "Отправить на почту" в новой таблице Excel или в теле письма в виде простого текста?

Comment: отправить в виде новой таблицы.

Comment: Excel таблицы имею ввиду

Comment: нашел кое какое решение, кому интересно будет пишите, оно мягко сказать не идеальное но работает